# Twitter API most tweeted

Tags: api, twitter

I understand the Twitter API is only getting more restricted, but is it possible to use the search API to find the most tweeted links within a given time period?

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible with the Twitter API. It is possible with Gnip (disclosure I work for Gnip), but to figure that out would be very costly. In essence what you would need to do is get every Tweet with a link in it and then from that dataset determine the most Tweeted links.